# Any possibility targeted ads still work in Safari private mode

Tags: safari, ios, advertisements, private-browsing

I have a friend that claims that she gets targeted ads in Safari in private mode. I've told her it's not possible, but she seem to be very sure about it. So I wonder, is this possible, at all? Alternatively, what can I say to her to convince her it's not possible?

Comment: Safari private mdoe just disables cookies.  Questions about iOS devices, and in particular Safari on iOS devices, are out of scope for Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is conceivable that targeted ads are based on IP address, which no non-rerouting client program can change. (Try [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) and see what happens.) Very determined ad sites might also be using browser properties, like installed fonts and screen resolution (among [others](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/improving-private-browsing-modes-do-not-track-vs-real-privacy-design)) to identify a client.

Of course, if you explicitly sign into any service in private browsing, it will know who you are and probably apply targeted ads.